# How can I automate publishing and referencing static content to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

To optimise the speed of my MVC3 Azure site it has been suggested that I should host my JS, CSS and image files (basically any static content) in Azure public containers with CDN enabled. These should then be linked to instead of being stored on the web role.

Is there anyway to automate this as part of a publishing the solution? So that I get underlining etc in VS2010?

Effectively anything that is stored in the local MVC3 content & scripts folder should be copied to Azure storage and referenced from there.

It seems like something that should be a straightforward option. Am I missing something obvious

Thanks

Comment: I know your point but I don't think there's any features in Azure SDK to help us to do this, for example automatically copy the static files to a blob storage and link to the CDN URL. If you want to copy the files manually, I'm not sure if it's help to map the CDN URL to local in your hosts file, so that you can test locally without changing the URLs in your pages.

Comment: Yeah will look at that. It is a real pity that by default you can't tell it to put static content elsewhere and reduce your load on your web role. If they made the Azure tooling a bit easier (and less prone to crashing)  I think they would get better uptake.

Comment: Maybe you can submit your request on this website, http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting and if many people are following you, it could be in the next version of azure SDK.

Comment: Someone beat me to it. http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/1484541-depoly-to-blob-storage-as-part-of-visual-studio-pu. Hopefully people will vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nathan Totten has created some very nice Helpers for using the Windows Azure CDN.

- [ASPX Helpers](http://nuget.org/packages/CdnHelpers.ASPX)
- [Razor Syntax Helpers](http://nuget.org/packages/CdnHelpers.Razor)

Comment: Seems like the best thing available

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie mentions it in his [recent unplugged talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2371) about using the config file to specify a virtual directory that is in blob storage to do this. However he seems to suggest that tighter integration is being worked on. So hopefully publish to the virtual directory et would be possible